# Does USB modems create a danger when used on routers?

Tags: deanonymization

I'm not sure if this is in the right place but it does have to do with exploits and ultimately de-anonymizing Tor.

Are USB internet modems dangerous to use, with and without a router (DD-WRT)? I'm not sure if they're considered uPnP but I've read several articles on the danger of USB modems as they can bypass secure systems. Most new routers now have USB ports to plug in USB modems. Anybody have an idea of the dangers?

Answer (score 1):

I use one all the time when I'm on the road.

I see it no different then using my regular net at home or using orbot on my cell phone. 
I have never seen a exploit that has to do with Tor and USB modems.

The traffic is sent as regular network packets from the OS.

The only exploit I can think of is if someone start loading the storage on it (that usually contains driver and software on many USB modems) with malware.